# MySQL query to return last values of a table complying a condition and limited by other condition

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `range` (
  `ts` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
  `f0` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  `f1` float(10,2) NOT NULL,
  ...
```

which rows describe ranges of float numbers `[f0-f1]`. This ranges may be increasing (i.e. `f0 < f1`) or decreasing (i.e. `f0 > f1`).

Ordering by `ts`, I'm searching for a query that returns the last increasing rows up to the first decreasing row. For instance,

```
+---------------------+------+------+
| ts                  | f0   | f1   |
+---------------------+------+------+
| ...                 | ...  | ...  |
| 2015-01-24 00:00:00 | 0.20 | 0.05 |
| 2015-01-25 00:00:00 | 0.10 | 0.20 |
| 2015-01-26 00:00:00 | 0.10 | 0.30 |
+---------------------+------+------+
```

the query would return the last two rows, and in case of

```
+---------------------+------+------+
| ts                  | f0   | f1   |
+---------------------+------+------+
| ...                 | ...  | ...  |
| 2015-01-24 00:00:00 | 0.10 | 0.20 |
| 2015-01-25 00:00:00 | 0.10 | 0.30 |
| 2015-01-26 00:00:00 | 0.20 | 0.05 |
+---------------------+------+------+
```

it would return 0 rows.

Any thoughts how to limit results based on a condition?

```
SELECT * FROM range WHERE f0 > f1 ORDER BY ts DESC LIMIT ???
```

Your help will be much appreciated.

Comment: As an aside - are you sure you want FLOATs as opposed to DECIMALs?

Comment: @Strawberry, I will consider your suggestion. Thanks. However, using float or decimal does not make any difference when comparing with `<` or `>`

Comment: @Al_ in my experience you will get strange automatic rounding issues with floats in mysql. for example 0.20 could suddenly be represented as 0.19 - and stuff like that. so i aggree with Strawberry - rather take DECIMALs.

Comment: So, basically you're looking for the "consecutive wins and losses pattern"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select *
from   range
where ts > (select max(ts)
            from range
            where f0 > f1)
order by ts
```

Comment: Yep, that's it! (of course using subqueries!). The condition is in fact `f0 < f1`. Many thanks.